# Compactness of $GL_n\left (\cal{K}\right)$ where $\cal{K}$ is cantor set

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following functions
$f:GL_n(\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\},f(A)=det(A),\forall A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$;
and $g:\mathbb{R}\to M_2(\mathbb{R}),
g(x)=\begin{pmatrix}  \cos x & -\sin x\\ \sin x & \cos x \end{pmatrix}, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$
Choose the correct one(s) from the statements given below:

a) Let $\cal{K}$ denote the cantor set and $GL_n(\cal{K})$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ invertible matrices
having entries from$\cal{K}$. Then $f(GL_n(\cal{K}))$ is closed

b) Let $\cal{K}$ be as above. Then $g(\cal{K})$ is closed

c) $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ has infinitely many closed subgroups contaning $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$

d) All the above three statements are true .
but what about the other options??

---

Option (b) is true as if $A=g(\cal{K})$ is open then $g^{-1}(A)$ is open as $g$ is continuous since each componants are continuous ,then $\cal{K}$ is open contradiction as $\cal{K}$ is closed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for (a).  $f$ extends to a continuous function from $\mathbb C^{n \times n}$ (the space of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C$) to $\mathbb C$, and $\mathcal K^{n \times n}$ is compact.
$f(GL_n(\mathcal K)) = f(\mathcal K^{n \times n}) \backslash \{0\}$ would not be closed in $\mathbb C$, but it is closed if the codomain is taken to be $\mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks... What about option c??

Comment: Think about the closure of the subgroup generated by $SL_n(\mathbb C)$ and a matrix of determinant $d$.